# The meaning of ${TF_CFLAGS[@]}

Tags: bash

From the Tensorflow [add a new op tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/adding_an_op), it uses:

```
TF_CFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_compile_flags()))') )
TF_LFLAGS=( $(python -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(" ".join(tf.sysconfig.get_link_flags()))') )
g++ -std=c++11 -shared zero_out.cc -o zero_out.so -fPIC ${TF_CFLAGS[@]} ${TF_LFLAGS[@]} -O2
```

I am wondering the meaning of `[@]` here.

Comment: It's a bash-ism. https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html#Arrays